# Rails beginner: Model-based User management

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, user-management, devise-invitable

I'm developing a web site with Topic, Subtopic and Article models. Users are able to sign up (devise gem) and create topics, subtopics under topics and articles under subtopics.

What I want to do is, a user should be able to invite an other user (member or not) 
- to show and edit a Topic with all the subtopics and articles, 
- OR to edit only a subtopic to show and edit all the articles 
- OR to edit only one article.

At this point, seems like I can use devise_invitable gem for inviting. But how can I show this invited user only the permitted objects?

Is there any gem or something to manage the application like this?

Comment: You should try building some of these features yourself. By-passing every problem using a gem isn't the right development methodology-- more often than not you'll find a gem that does exactly what you need but again you won't learn anything

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check out [`cancancan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) for dealing with user permissions.